# How to develop a web application in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I have installed alfresco community edition and want to develop a web application having database connectivity.

I have developed that application using jsp, servlets but want to develop the same application in alfresco.

Can anybody help where to start?

Answer (score 4):

I have written a [series of tutorials](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series) for people new to the Alfresco platform. I humbly submit those as a good place to start. There are also a number of [books](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Books) available on Alfresco.

It is a little hard to tell what you are trying to do from your brief description, but if you are trying to perform CRUD operations against the repository, I strongly suggest that you start with the Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) standard because that gives you a vendor-neutral, language independent way to talk to Alfresco or any other CMIS-compliant repository. My tutorials cover CMIS. You also might be interested in [OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html), which includes a CMIS client API for Java.

That should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

One of the more documented ways is to use Alfresco Web Services Client (I am using alfresco-web-service-client-3.4.d). Its a SOAP client generated from the WSDL provided by Alfreco.
There are good examples on the web. Google for Alfresco+Web+Services+Ingres.

Answer (score 1):

If you have developed the application, then it will definitely help you know the flow and understanding of the application.

You need to play around with alfresco, check their website: http://www.alfresco.com/

Comment: thanks for the reply

but i am new to alfresco and can't understand how to integrate my application.
the application which i develop is using netbeans but can't find any way of its integration in alfresco.
i don't find any suitable material on alfresco.com
can u help me i telling where to start. i don't even know how to make a static website in alfresco.

thanks in advance